# iterative algorithm for combination generation

Tags: algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Algorithm to return all combinations of k elements from n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n)

Is there any iterative algorithm  to generate combinations of  N numbers taking 'r' at a time ?

Comment: can you post an example?

Comment: Consider a set of 10 items: `A B C D E F G H I J`.

If r=2, what do you expect?

`AB BC CD DE EF FG GH GI IJ` or `AB AC AD AE AF AG AH AI AJ BC BD BE ...` ?

Comment: This subject has been deal with here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n

Comment: @BilltheLizard Is this really a duplicate? The question asks for an **iterative** algorithm, which is not required by the other question, nor (I think) dealt with in the answers.

Comment: This not a duplicate. It specifically asks for an iterative algorithm.

Comment: This not a duplicate. It specifically asks for an *iterative* algorithm.

Answer (score 14):

Yes there is.

Here is code from the [wrong answer Library](http://code.google.com/p/wrong-answer-library/).

```
void generate_combos(int n, int k) {
    int com[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) com[i] = i;
    while (com[k - 1] < n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
            cout << com[i] << " ";
        cout << endl;

        int t = k - 1;
        while (t != 0 && com[t] == n - k + t) t--;
        com[t]++;
        for (int i = t + 1; i < k; i++) com[i] = com[i - 1] + 1;
    }
}
```

This generates the combinations in lexicographic order.